# To follow-up or not to follow-up (interviewed, not offered "yet")

Tags: job-search, job-offer

I am in bit of a situation here. I have been looking for new job opportunities for a while and was contacted by a well known company for a very good position. The telephone interview and in-person interview went extremely well and the manager verbally confirmed the offer, however since I am in immigrant status they wanted to run my work authorization documentations by their immigration attorney before they put a formal offer. My immigration situation is very simple, however, it's been almost a month or more that they have been reviewing my documents and every time I follow-up they say that "the attorney is going to come back with a recommendation shortly...". My (personal) Immigration Attorney says that there is not much to review and it shouldn't take months to decide whether to proceed or not for an attorney.

Meanwhile, I got called from another company B and their processes are moving rather quickly and I already have an offer from them. They are also ready to start my immigration documentation processing immediately since their attorney already reviewed and gave the green light.

Now, I am more interested on the first opportunity but I am in bit of a rush here since I have been looking for a long time and my home lease contract is about to expire which I would not want to renew if I don't have to, plus, a couple of other personal/financial engagements at my current location that wouldn't be meaningful anymore if I were to leave. And I need to make decisions on these quickly. And I have a kid, so I need to look for schools, admissions, etc. In addition to that, the current work is becoming un-bearable by the day.

I am in a dilemma of whether I should follow up with the first company and be honest with them about (1) the other opportunity that I have (2) my urgency in order to make some of my personal decisions quickly, while showing that I am still very interested in that position. I am also worried that if I wait for the first opportunity too long that I might lose the second one at hand.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you could do is reach out to the company(which gave you a verbal 'offer') and inform them about the status of your offer from the other company.

If you decide to wait on the first offer it could also end up backfiring on you in the event that the company decides to withdraw their 'offer'.

Given your current situation along with your personal/ financial engagements, I suggest you try reaching out to the the company which gave you a verbal 'offer' first, inform them of your current situation and listen to what they have to say. If things are moving too slowly and you have other commitments I suggest you move ahead with the other offer.

In the end, only you can decide what is the best course of action. While it would be nice to work at the company you're more interested in, you don't want to spend a lot of your time waiting on them only to have it not work out in the end.

All the best and congratulations on both of your offers!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am also wondering if the first company is trying to evaluate other candidates and at the same time doesn't want to say "no" to me. I am very inclined to follow up and let them know the situation but I am worried if they think i am "leveraging" the other offer in any way.

Comment: @Annjawn I was going to add this in as well. The company could most certainly be doing this(confirming verbal 'offers' with multiple candidates) so that if their top choice backs out of the offer, they have other people who are waiting in line. As with any job related negotiations, anything that you say can be interpreted in numerous ways by the other party especially when bringing up other potential job offers. You can inform the company that you have another offer and if you don't hear back from them by a certain date, you will proceed with the other offer.